# Can I use VB.NET to develop applications using MonoDroid?

Tags: android, vb.net, xamarin.android

I would like to know if it is possible to develop smartphone applications using VB.NET rather than C# with the MonoDroid Visual Studio addin?

Also, if possible could anyone point me in the right direction of some example code in VB.NET not C#?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an article
From http://mono-android.net/FAQ

> Currently Mono for Android does not support Visual Basic.
>
> We are looking at adding support for
>   Visual Basic on upcoming versions of
>   Mono for Android.
>
> Technically, what needs to happen is
>   the following: we need to provide the
>   Visual Basic helper library (part of
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll) and compile
>   it to work with the Mono for Android
>   mscorlib.dll instead of the standard
>   Mono 2.0 mscorlib.dll
>
> With the above it will be possible to
>   use Microsoft's Visual Studio to
>   compile VB code that will run on Mono
>   for Android. But we want to support
>   Mono's own Visual Basic compiler, but
>   that will also require the compiler to
>   run using the Mono for Android
>   mscorlib.dll. This is not difficult,
>   but requires time to get done and
>   integrate into our release process.
>
> At this point there is no ETA on when
>   the above will happen. [enter link
>   description here][1]
>
> [1]: http://mono-android.net/FAQ

Answer (score 1):

Not at this time. You can find an explanation in [the FAQ](http://mono-android.net/FAQ), but the first few lines state:

> Does Mono for Android support Visual
>   Basic?
>
> Currently Mono for Android does not
>   support Visual Basic.
>
> We are looking at adding support for
>   Visual Basic on upcoming versions of
>   Mono for Android.